# Add-TeamUser Powershell Teams doesn't take affect on Teams App [Resolved - Closing]

Tags: azure, powershell, microsoft-teams

We are trying to populate msTeam by using Teams Powerhsell Add-TeamUser cdmlets, when we run

```
Add-TeamUser -GroupId:"GROUPEID" -User:"USERID" -Role:Member
```

we have no error and the change take effect on our Azure Active Directory (cf. the user was added to the AAD Group). But we doesn't see the Team on Teams App.

EDIT : Sorry for losing important information the account user we are looking to add was 'guest' - user from other organization (cf. Other AAD external)

EDIT : Other point the User was added on AAD Group (equivalent of Teams Team)
But it doesn't appear on the Teams Member screen 
[image]

Note: when we using the Teams Button Add Member the user was added perfectly. But now we are trying to use powershell because we have most account to adding on different Team.

Thanks in advance.

Ressources : 
[MsTeamsPowershell](https://opdhsblobprod03.blob.core.windows.net/contents/d71dcd356aee4ddcb6e19316b9d351e8/733454087bfb9db10cfb3fe1ea6e0abf?sv=2015-04-05&sr=b&sig=6LnlFtvYAgDXGOwyQGnkIVupG5lp%2BkeO%2FIydjSu4Qy4%3D&st=2019-01-07T12%3A42%3A20Z&se=2019-01-08T12%3A52%3A20Z&sp=r) 
[Package_MicrosoftTeams_0.9.5](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/MicrosoftTeams/0.9.5)

Edit closed :Bad reading documentation see comment

Further, and perhaps more important, quote from the docs: "Note: the command will return immediately, but the Teams application will not reflect the update immediately. The Teams application may need to be open for up to an hour before changes are reflected." – gvee 18 mins ago

Comment: I assume you've exited the Teams application and re-opened it?

Comment: @gvee Yes we have trying all off thoses, exited clearing cache reopened using other plateforme like (mobile) but it doesn't take effect.

Comment: From the docs on [`Add-TeamUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/teams/add-teamuser): _"Note: This cmdlet is currently in Beta."_ Therefore I suspect the better place to ask is on the GitHub issues page related to the CmdLet as it may be a bug.

Comment: Further, and perhaps more important, quote from the docs: _"Note: **the command will return immediately, but the Teams application will not reflect the update immediately.** The Teams application may need to be open for up to an hour before changes are reflected."_

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the described problem is covered in the official Microsoft documentation.

Comment: @gvee yes i'm going to open issues on GitHub.